# Convert String Variable to Datetime Returns Incorrect Value in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Following my question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387418/where-clause-using-date-taken-from-string-variable-sent-out-incorrect-return-in-s, this is the simplified version of the question:

The query used for the OLE DB Source is this, with a string type variable inside:

```
select
  *
from
  A
where
  A.A_IN_DATETIME < CONVERT(DATETIME,?,105) and
  (A.A_OUT_DATETIME is NULL or A.A_OUT_DATETIME >= CONVERT(DATETIME,?,105))
```

The query above works inside a Foreach Variable Enumerator, with the variable used is an array of string variable consisting of this: 13-09-2011,12-09-2011,11-09-2011,10-09-2011,09-09-2011,08-09-2011,07-09-2011,06-09-2011,05-09-2011,04-09-2011,03-09-2011,02-09-2011,01-09-2011

The condition for the problem is this: For example, there is a record in A with A_IN_DATETIME = 2011-09-12 (YYYY-MM-DD format) and A_OUT_DATETIME = NULL.

The correct result for the query above that it should have been only returning values for 13-09-2011 and the rest return 0 records, but in the execution, there was a result for 12-09-2011 to 10-09-2011 also. I don't know if the SSIS somehow mistaken the 12-09-2011, 11-09-2011, 10-09-2011 to 09-12-2011,09-11-2011,09-10-2011 (FYI, I've checked the parsing result and also the loop enumerator by printing it out in a message box generated from the script task, and it is still in its correct form).

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Answer (score 0):

Run Sql Profiler and see what query comes through to SQL Server. This will allow you to re-run the exact query in SSMS and see the results right there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe conversion to DATETIME accepts a format, i.e. `105`.Try this instead:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '9/13/2011 15:37:00')
```

Result is DATETIME - 2011-09-13 15:37:00.000

Comment: 105 is valid when converting a DATETIME to a string (VARCHAR, etc.)

Comment: agreed, i read your comment wrong. was thinking of converting to a varchar instead of the other way around.